# Save values in two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read lines from a .txt-file which works good so far.
The point i'm struggling with is that the file contains two values per line, which I want to save in two different arrays. 
The textfile looks like the following:

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiUuP.png)

My method so far looks like that: (saves the values in only one array)

```
    File file = new File(txt);

    if (!file.canRead() || !file.isFile())  // Prüfen ob Datei gelesen werden kann
        System.exit(0);

    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
        String zeile = null;
        int zeilennummer = 0;
        // Es wird solange gelesen wie Zeilen vorhanden sind
        while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
            teilen = zeile.split("    "); // Zeile wird an Leerzeichen gesplittet
            zeilennummer++;


            preis = new int[anzahlTanstellen];

            // alle Entfernungen und Preise der Tankstellen
            if (zeilennummer > 5) {
                for (int i = 0; i < teilen.length; i++) {
                    preis[i] = Integer.parseInt(teilen[i]);
                    System.out.println(preis[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Bei Fehlern wird eine IO-Exception geworfen
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Apart from this, you should always post a well-formatted code and comments written in English.

Comment: Sorry for this, i am new here. The question is already described. I want to save the different values in one row from the text-file in 2 different arrays. thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes your goal is to have two lists/arrays, one containing the values of the first column of values in the file and the other containing the values of the second column.

Since you know each row contains two columns, treat it as such, instead of using a for loop on the split result. See my comments and changes in the code below.

```
File file = new File(txt);

if (!file.canRead() || !file.isFile())  // Prüfen ob Datei gelesen werden kann
    System.exit(0);

// use arraylists because you don't know how many lines are in the file
ArrayList<Integer> column1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> column2 = new ArrayList<>();

BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
    String zeile = null;
    int zeilennummer = 0;
    // Es wird solange gelesen wie Zeilen vorhanden sind
    while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
        teilen = zeile.split("    "); // Zeile wird an Leerzeichen gesplittet
        zeilennummer++;

        // this is replaced by the two arraylists
        //preis = new int[anzahlTanstellen];

        // alle Entfernungen und Preise der Tankstellen
        if (zeilennummer > 5) {
            if(teilen.length != 2) {
                // handle this error. skip the line maybe? ignore? throw an exception?
            } else {
                // store the first value in column1 and the second in column2
                column1.add(Integer.parseInt(teilen[0]));
                column2.add(Integer.parseInt(teilen[1]));
            }
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // Bei Fehlern wird eine IO-Exception geworfen
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null)
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}

// now do whatever you want with your two columns
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it as described!

Answer (score -1):

After reading the line trim it and then use StringTokenizer class to tokenize/split it. First token will have first number and 2nd token will have 2nd number. store them into two different arraylist.